# Table formatting: fit-to-content option?

Tags: feature-request, formatting, tables

Would it be possible to have tables which are sized to fit the contents, rather than using the full width available?

Something like this, but with the last column hidden.

| Id | Name | Quest | Favourite colour | ******************** |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 24601 | Valjean | Bread | Redemption |  |
| 0118-999 | Moss | Firefighting | Plaid |  |

Comment: The frontend table parser is happy with no line break but the backend one requires a newline.

Comment: Just wondering what the practical use for this would be? I usually see data in need of being easier to copy, not easier on the eyes.

Comment: It would bring beauty to the world, and joy to the hearts of children, @MisterMiyagi

Comment: It was a two-column table, where column A was `id, 1, 2, 3`, whnch prompted this question.